# How to make a image resize to fit a div

Tags: html, css

Right now i am programming my site with a slideshow. I have the whole slideshow made but i have a little issue. I want any image i link to re-size to fit the width and height no matter if its smaller or bigger, i don't care if it maintains the aspect ratio or not. The problem is i have the div set to fill the page width 100% and when i set the image to width 100% and height 100% it doesn't change it just stays the same. How can i make the image smaller but still show the full image?

HTML:

```
<div class="sliderContent">
     <div class="item" style="height: 280px; width:100%; z-index: 4; display: none; background: url(img/img1.png) 50% 50% no-repeat black;">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.sliderContent {
float:left;
width:100%;
max-width: 100%;
max-height: 100%;
height:280px;
clear:both;
position:relative;
overflow:hidden;
}

#item {
max-width: 100%;
max-height: 100%; 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `background-size: 100% 100%`.

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gv5gs0tp/)

```css
.sliderContent {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  height: 280px;
  clear: both;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.item {
  height: 280px;
  width:100%;
  z-index: 4;
  background: url(http://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff) no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="sliderContent">
  <div class="item">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you set your images as background with css this might help:

```
.sliderContent .item { background-size:cover;}
```